# I tried to set a function to send a toast and play a sound when given an input but it did not work as I anticipated (react-native)

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native, so there are still some blank spaces. But I am trying to fill them by developing projects. In my current project, I am trying to develop an app which can support the vocabulary learning for English learners. In one screen, user sees a definition of the word and tries to guess the word by giving an input and pressing enter key on the keyboard. **The issue is, whenever i guess the word incorrectly, it sends the toast and plays the sound so it works on incorrect guessing. But when i guess it correctly, it also sends the toast and plays the incorrect sound.** Here is what I did:

Here is my textinput(from react native paper) code:

```
<TextInputGuess 
            label="Guess!" 
            mode="outlined" 
            onEndEditing={checkWord} 
            onChangeText={text => setInput(text)}
          />
```

Then, here is the checkWord function, which checks the input and compares the real answer and the input:

```
const checkWord = () => {
  console.log(currentCard.word, input)
  if (currentCard.word.trim().toLowerCase() === input.trim().toLowerCase() ) {
     CorrectWord();
  } else {
     WrongWord();
  }
};
```

And the WrongWord and CorrectWord functions:

```
const CorrectWord = () => {
  playCorrectSound()
};


const WrongWord = () => {
  toast.show('Oops, the word is not correct. Please try again', 500);
  playSound();
  };
```

And here is the sound function for the wrong answer and correct answer, respectively:

```
const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();

  async function playSound() {
    //console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync( require('../../../assets/sounds/incorrect.mp3')
    );
    setSound(sound);

    //console.log('Playing Sound');
    await sound.playAsync();
  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log('Unloading Sound');
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);
};



const [correctSound, setCorrectSound] = React.useState();

  async function playCorrectSound() {
    console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { correctSound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync( require('../../../assets/sounds/positive-beeps.mp3')
    );
    setSound(correctSound);

    console.log('Playing Sound');
    await correctSound.playAsync();
  

    React.useEffect(() => {
      return correctSound
        ? () => {
            console.log('Unloading Sound');
            correctSound.unloadAsync();
          }
        : undefined;
    }, [correctSound]);
  };
```

Thank you to everyone in advance who spares their time. If you feel like you need more information, please ask me to send them.

I couldn't do so many things because my knowledge is limited. I mainly utilized the code that I found from internet for example sound playing functions. That is why i couldn't do so much. Instead, I tried to get help from a friend and he also couldn't provide any solution.

Comment: Its quite hard to say whats going on given you havent provided the inputs. I think there's a good chance that your code works fine, just your true condition is never met. Can you put it into a console log and see the outcome like this -console.log(currentCard.word.trim().toLowerCase() === input.trim().toLowerCase())

Comment: Hello @redberry. After I had posted, I have changed onEndEditing to onSubmitEditing. This solved the problem about the code giving the wrong answer even if i guess the word correctly. But still, there was no sound playing when I guess the word right. In playCorrectSoun(), I have changed const {correctSound} and setSound(correctSound) to const{sound} setSound(sound). After that, the problem was solved completely. I have figured out the problem 5 minutes ago and I was on my way to close this. Sorry about my typing because Im on my mobile Phone right now. And also thanks for helping.